# Convert Chinese character to Unicode using PHP

Tags: php

Is there a way in PHP to convert Chinese characters to Unicode?

```
e.g. (買嘢) convert to (&#36023 ;&#22050 ;)
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773863/converting-non-unicode-non-english-content-to-unicode

Comment: Why would you even use unicode NCRs ?

Answer (score 5):

```
function chineseToUnicode($str){
    //split word
    preg_match_all('/./u',$str,$matches);

    $c = "";
    foreach($matches[0] as $m){
            $c .= "&#".base_convert(bin2hex(iconv('UTF-8',"UCS-4",$m)),16,10);
    }
    return $c;
}
//Print result
$str = "雨傘運動或稱雨傘革命、遮打運動、遮打革命（英語：Umbrella Movement 或 Umbrella Revolution）是於2014年9月26日起在香港為爭取真普選而發起的一系列公民抗命，逾60-70萬（人次）香港市民佔據多個主要商業區靜坐及示威，地點包括金鐘、中環、灣仔、銅鑼灣、旺角和尖沙咀，旨在要求包括撤回中國全國人大常委會（人大常委）所確定之2017年行政長官選舉及2016年立法會選舉框架和候選人提名方案，爭取行政長官選舉的公民提名權及取消立法會功能界別等訴求。";
echo chineseToUnicode($str);
```

http://pastebin.com/zZfci0Dz

**For Ryan** (utf8 to unicode + unicode to utf8)

Full Example Code in PHP

http://ideone.com/td1TUv

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do the opposite of this. (I want Unicode to Chinese characters.)  Do you know how? Thanks.

Comment: Ryan, function of unicode to chinese is ready, please check again